# jQuery.load in Opera 10.6 not firing complete

Tags: jquery, opera

Opera is the only browser giving trouble with this jQuery statement:

```
$("select").load("options.html",function() { $(this).val("de"); });
```

The SELECT does not fill with ANY options.  It is blank.  Worse, I can turn on DragonFly in an effort to trace it down, and the problem disappears.  The options are displayed as they should.

Anyone come across this?

HTML as requested:

```
<select class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
     <option value="en">English</option>
     <option value="de">Deutsch</option>
</select>
```

Obviously, the OPTIONs aren't there to start with...

Comment: Works for me in Opera 10.6.1. Not firing at all? You've tried an `alert()`? Edit your question to show your `<select>` and `<option>` tags, but first, go back and "Accept" some answers to your previous questions. http://stackoverflow.com/users/300144/ollie2893

Comment: Edit as per your request.  Yes, I tried alerts.  Get the one before, not the one inside.  I'd guess from the difference in behaviour between DragonFly and not that this is a timing issue.  I have not actually tried to catch the "load" event.  Perhaps there's coding bug in jQuery.

Comment: No, I can't catch the "load" event either...

Comment: Just upgraded to 10.61 - no change. I do not get the alert on complete.

Comment: Ollie2893 - Can you show your code with the alert? Again, this is working perfectly for me. I added an answer, but the `alert()` issue is confusing me.

Comment: I believe you.  If it's a timing issue, then it's perfectly possible that it works for you.  I really don't know what there's to write about alerts:

    alert(1);
    $("select").load("options.html",function() { 
       alert(2);
       $(this).val("de");
    });

Comment: My apologies, I didn't look closely enough at the question. I was hung up on the callback and didn't notice that you're not getting the options at all. What method are you using to ensure the DOM is loaded?

Comment: Good question!  The entire code runs inside $().  However, the .load was one of the first instructions to execute.  I just moved the lot down into last position.  And, hey presto, problem solved.  Go figure...

Comment: Glad you worked it out. Opera must show a fully loaded `<body>` tag before its content is fully loaded. Not good!

Comment: Incidentally, Patrick, I just figured out that .val("de") only works in modern browsers.  IE6 pukes.  Better to use
   $("option[value='xx']",this).attr("selected","selected");

Comment: That's strange too. I know IE6 has trouble with the native `this.value` when the `<option>` elements don't have a `value` property assigned. But `.val()` should correct those issues. Are you using the latest jQuery (1.4 or later)? Also, you may want to post your solution as an answer for the benefit of future readers.

Answer (score 0):

To repeat a comment from above:  the problem was solved by moving the .load call further down the list of instructions inside the $.ready function.  This is not the first time that I notice that Opera's JS engine appears to get ahead of itself.  It would seem that the DOM-ready is fired before everything is truly ready.

Comment: Hi Ollie,
would it be possible to give me a link to the page you're working on with some instructions regarding where the code was/is? I'd like to check out this problem to see if we can fix it in Opera's core.